# Why mouseover is not detecting other div which is on another div in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am adding mouseover event. According to my HTML code, the `myDiv` is appearing exactly on `<img>`. I am detecting mouseover on both `<img>` and `myDiv`.

But what happens, when I hover a mouse on `<img>` its working fine and it's detecting that it's hovered on image but when I hover on `myDiv` without leaving  `<img>`, it's not detecting `myDiv`, it's still in `<img>`. How can I detect myDiv without leaving img.

Below is my code

 
My HTML code

```
<style>
 .myDiv{
     position:absolute;
  }
 .hoverEffect{
     border: 2px solid #0044ff;
     opacity: 0.5;
  }
</style>
<div class="myDiv">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
<img src="myimage.jpg">
```

JQuery Code

```
$('body').mouseover(function(e) {
      //e.target For Detecting div or image
      $(e.target).addClass('hoverEffect');
});
$('body').mouseout(function(e) {
     $(e.target).removeClass('hoverEffect');
}
```

In below GIF image, you can see content "WELCOME TO OUR APP" in above image. And after hovering on image, it's not detecting this content which has another div.

In above JQuery code, I've added the class "`hoverEffect`" to hovered `div`. The only problem is in `hoverEffect` class and that is opacity. When I use opacity then it's not detecting `myDiv` but when I remove opacity from css code then it's working fine. 

[Working jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/8sbxhqgd/) (without using opacity) 
[Not Working jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/w6ezx38a/2/) (with opacity)

My question is, why it's not working when I add opacity to the class?
If it's possible to do it without removing opacity from class then how to do this?

Comment: Its working for both

Comment: @NikhilGhuse Please try to hover on "Hello World" on both jsfiddle and check the behaviour of both

Comment: Yes I have  check both

Comment: Ok now I got it as the answer is posted you need to chenge z-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `z-index`, Try to change css like this

```
.myDiv{
  position:absolute;
  z-index : 9;
}
.myDiv h4{
  z-index : 99;
}
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/w6ezx38a/3/

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I am not able to understand that how opacity is affecting to behavior? And can we resolve it by js or Jquery code? because I am taking the HTML as dynamic in JQuery code, you can say without changing CSS / HTML, can we fix it?

Comment: Yes you can make class in css and add/remove by jquery